# Vertically center child element, but allow parent to expand when child overflows

Tags: css, css-position

I'm looking for a css-only solution to this problem. I have a parent and a child div. The parent has a minimum height. When the child div has a smaller height, I want it to be vertically centered in the parent. But when the child div expands past the parent's min-height, I want the parent to expand.

Illustrated in this image:
[image]

I can come close; `position: relative` on the child allows me to affect the parent height while still positioning the child, but I can't figure out how to determine the correct position (`top: 50%` plus `transform: translateY` won't work for me since the parent's height is not fixed).

This one has me stumped! Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with flex:

```css
.container {
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
}

.container>div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto; /* Center vertically */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>some content</div>
</div>
```

With bigger content height:

```css
.container {
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container>div {
  height: 800px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks good! I won't be able to test before Monday, I'll get around to accepting a working answer after that.